# $(document).ready doesn't work however page is loaded

Tags: ajax, jquery

As you can understand my title, browser doesn't call the `GetReleatedProducts` method. I put breakpoint `$(document).ready(function ()` line but it doesn't enter into ajax call. 
I checked that I have jquery reference. Do you have any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:2782/AjaxCallPage.aspx/GetReleatedProducts",
        data: "{productId:" + productId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {...}
```

Comment: Any error on console ?

Comment: first of all, you don't pass data as string, you pass it as an object. So: `data: { productId: productId }` would do the trick. Maybe it even solves the issue...?

Comment: @PetrČihula: You can pass it as a string if you like. (If you do, though, you have to encode it properly yourself.)

Comment: @pXL no there is no error.

Comment: @cagin: What is the URL of the document this code is in? In particular, does it *also* start with `http://localhost:2782`?

Comment: Is the AJAX call not being made or is the `success` function not firing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use url rooting but domain name is the same. it is http://localhost:2782/Urun/Sasy-Ceket/65/0

Comment: @cagin: Importantly, both domain (`localhost`) **and** port (`2782`) are the same, so it's not an [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.

Comment: If you're trying to call PageMethods using Jquery Post, make sure you've necessary refrence in web.config. Check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21372/Adding-ASP-NET-AJAX-to-an-Existing-ASP-NET-Applica)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think so it is not about SOP. I use this code block in another page and it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told the server you're sending it JSON:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

...but what you're sending it:

```
data: "{productId:" + productId + "}",
```

...is not *valid* JSON. To be valid JSON, the key `productId` must be in double quotes:

```
data: '{"productId":' + productId + '}',
//      ^         ^
```

(Here I'm assuming `productId` is a number. If it's a string, it will also need to be in double quotes.)

So I suspect the server side is rejecting the call because the JSON is invalid.

It's also a bit unusual to send JSON *to* the server, although it's perfectly valid if that server is coded to expect it and if you send it correctly. It's more typical to send data to the server using the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So unless you've coded your server side to expect to receive JSON, remove the `contentType` option from your `$.ajax` call and change `data` to:

```
data: {productId: productId}
```

...which tells jQuery to do the encoding for you.

Comment: @cagin: The code quoted in the question is fine other than as described above (and the fact it trails off -- oh, and I assume `productId` is defined somewhere in the containing scope). There's nothing for it but to walk through with a debugger (both client-side and server-side). If you still aren't finding the problem, create an [absolutely minimal, self-contained project](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem and post all of the code and config to the question. Someone using ASP.Net may be able to point to the specific bit that's not right.

Comment: It was my foolish mistake.. I didn't set my webservice method as static.. Thanks for your all suggestions.

Comment: @cagin: Ah! I'm glad you sorted it out. The best thing to do is to post your own answer saying that (which is perfectly fine to do) and then accept it once SO allows you to (two days later). I'll leave this answer here as I think it had/has useful information for folks who may find it later...